# Base de datos relacionales, ¿tengo demasiadas tablas para algo tan sencillo?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

tengo una pequeña duda.

Estoy creando una base de datos relacional con MySql y tenía varias dudas en cuanto a las tablas.

Tengo que crear una tabla usuario donde se relaciona con otras tablas de muchos a muchos, entonces entiendo que no me queda otra que hacer una tabla Usuario y luego tablas intermedias para conectar con las otras tablas. ¿Esto sería correcto?

Lo que me encuentro luego de hacer las tablas de esta manera, es que a la hora de hacer una query se convierte en algo complejo con más de 5 joins, entonces quizás sea correcto y para consultar deba crearme una vista, o quizás este planteando mal mi solución y de ahí que tengas tantas joins.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

¡Saludos!

Comment: ¿Evaluar el diseño de una BDD únicamente por el número de JOINs? Lo que es sencillo para ti puede ser complejo para otro.

Comment: La verdad que tal como lo tengo montado, a nivel estructural lo veo bastante sencillo, pero luego al obtener los datos veo que tengo la clase usuario, que esta a su vez tiene una clase que dentro tiene otra. Máximo tres niveles de anidamiento, pero entiendo que es un problema.

Muchas gracias por vuestro aporte.

Comment: En un diseño de base de datos lo ideal es tener las tablas que necesites. Existen estructuras tan complejas como sencillas. "Depende" es una palabra que vas a escuchar mucho en esta carrera. Así que, *depende* de qué tan complejo sea tu caso de uso. Por cierto, esta pregunta está basada en opiniones y tal vez termine cerrada. Por favor visita nuestro centro de ayuda para saber [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Te recomiendo que, aunque sea una App pequeña, diseñes pensando a lo grande, porque esa App pequeña puede crecer en el futuro y si diseñas bien desde el principio no tendrás que modificar nada. Si diseñas pensando en pequeño puede que luego tengas que cambiar el diseño. Por lo general, se diseña una tabla para cada entidad: `Persona, Usuario, Categoria`. En el modelo de datos, puede que una entidad herede de otra, etc. Algo que ayuda mucho es **diseñar pensando en la realidad misma**. Tú puedes diseñar clases y mapear los resultados de las consultas a esas clases, o usar DAO, etc.

Comment: Perfecto! Muchas gracias por vuestras respuestas, tiraré pues como lo tenía, tabla por entidad.

Answer (score 1):

Estimado, actualmente yo estoy manejando un proyecto donde la tabla usuario se conecta con más de 20 tablas y esas tablas se comunican con otras tablas. Esto no tiene por qué ser un problema, tu base de datos debe ser tan grande como sea requerida para lo que estés haciendo.

Como recomendación, trata de manejar todo esto lo más ordenado posible a tu manera, si para ti es más ordenado mantener cada cosa en una tabla distinta (aunque pueda estar en única tabla), haz que esto no sea un problema y sea algo positivo dentro de su estructura.

Comment: Buen aporte, la verdad.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por el aporte, tendré en cuenta lo que me comentas. Quizá entonces el problema no lo tenga en las tablas, si no de como recojo esos datos en el back, haciendo una clase usuario, que dentro tiene una lista de categorias, que esta a su vez tiene una lista de subcategorias. Tendré que ver como mapeo eso y si la forma de rellenar esos datos es mejor hacer una query con joins o hacer para las categorias una select a parte y luego juntarlo.